# jQuery Selector Optimisation

Tags: jquery, performance

The following code works fine, however I'm unsure as to how efficient it might be, and wanted to put the feelers out to the experts if they could suggest better alternatives; which then hopefully I can comprehend the *how and why* and code more efficiently in the future.

```
$('.sub-level').slideUp(0);
$('.active + .sub-level').slideDown(0);
$('.active').parents('.sub-level').slideDown(0);
```

This jQuery script closes and opens the appropriate sub-menus when the page first loads. It's based on the following HTML sample:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="audio">Audio</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="computing">Computing</a>
    <ul class="sub-level sub-level-1">
      <li><a href="laptops">Laptops</a></li>
      <li><a class="active" href="netbooks">Netbooks</a></li>
      <li><a href="ipads-tablets-ereaders">iPads, tablets &amp; eReaders</a></li>
      <li><a href="desktop-pcs">Desktop PCs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="photography">Photography</a>
    <ul class="sub-level sub-level-1">
      <li><a href="dslr">DSLR</a></li>
      <li><a href="compact-cameras">Compact Cameras</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The idea is I need to close all the sub-menus immediately (using `slideUp()` so that jQuery records the height, otherwise when `slideDown()` is later called the animation is jumpy), but I need to keep open the sub-menu of the current menu item (which is classed as 'active').

I was thinking that because I'm closing all the menus, and then look to reopen a specific menu (there is potential for multiple sub-menus also), it doesn't seem particularly efficient - there's *always* a better way!

Comment: what do you want to archieve with the second line of code?

Comment: Apologies I should've explained better - the second and third lines of code reopens the menu for the current category (including subcategories). Originally I tried to leave these open by excluding those items using jQuery's `:not` but I couldn't seem to get it work properly - I found that this way worked exactly how I needed, but it just seem inefficient closing and reopening the menu. I don't have enough knowledge of how JS runs in the browser to really know.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into details of this particular example, you asked about making selectors more efficient. The best way to do that is to use `id` in your tags and then you don't even need jQuery, just `document.getElementById(myid)`.

Classes are nice for organizing your CSS, but for efficiency of Javascript, ids work the best.

Of course if you really want efficiency, you would not be doing so much animation either.

You may think that ids would not work in the structure that you have, but it is possible to do something with ids like this:

```
alevel1
  blevel1
    clevel1
alevel2
  blevel2
alevel3
  blevel3
    clevel3
```

It means that you would need to change the ids if you insert things, and keep track of the level (a, b, c) and the subtree number (1, 2, 3), not to mention constructing the ids to use in the selectors. You would also need to change the id to tag the `active` element.

Here is a jsfiddle that shows changing the ID http://jsfiddle.net/V7MZ5/

Comment: Animation is a client requirement.

I can see how IDs would be more efficient for selecting DOM objects. I think the trade off for the extra amount of coding required to do so (the menu is generated dynamically server-side) with IDs wouldn't provide enough gains to make it worth it.

My question was more to see if there was a better way to do what I am doing, maybe by chaining the methods or something.

I guess at times we get so used to looking for the optimised solution that sometimes we forget that the simple solution can sometimes be the best - especially when it's the client's dollar.